# Cant to read this Realtime Database firebase to flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a confusion with real time database and stream builder in flutter, as real time database is used for real time changes in the app, also stream builder performs same job for real time changes,

[image]

and this for rtdb

[image]

and this my code for return value humidyty, temperature, and time stamp

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  late final stream = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('data').child('environment').onValue;
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
  void signUserOut() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }

  int counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            StreamBuilder(
              stream: stream,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  final data = snapshot.data?.snapshot.value as Map?;
                  if (data == null) {
                    return Text('No data');
                  }
                  final humidity = data['humidity'];
                  final temperature = data['temperature'];
                  final timestamp = data['Ts'].toString();
                  return Stack(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 70, left: 10),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "SHOWCASE",
                              style: whiteTextStyle.copyWith(
                                  fontSize: 20, fontWeight: bold),
                            ),
                            Spacer(),
                            IconButton(
                              onPressed: signUserOut,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 110,
                          left: 10,
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              child: Text(
                                "Water Management",
                                style: whiteTextStyle.copyWith(fontSize: 16),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 210,
                          left: 10,
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              child: Text(
                                "Water Climate",
                                style: whiteTextStyle.copyWith(fontSize: 16),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                            Container(
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  ParamWaterClimate(
                                      nameSensor: 'Temp (°C)',
                                      valueSensor: '$temperature'),
                                  ParamWaterClimate(
                                    nameSensor: 'Humidity (%)',
                                    valueSensor: '$humidity',
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 350, left: 10),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  GraphScreen(

                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                }
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  print(snapshot.error.toString());
                  return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
                }
                return Text('....');
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

how can i read sensor humidyty, temperature, dan time stamp epoch?

Answer (score 0):

Your data has a level of so-called push keys (the keys starting with `-N...` in your screenshot) that your code failed to handle. To handle this level in your data, loop over the `children` of the snapshot:

```
builder: (context, snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasData) {
    final dataSnapshot = snapshot.data!
    for (final childSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
        final data = childSnapshot.value as Map?;
        final humidity = data['humidity'];
        final temperature = data['temperature'];
        final timestamp = data['Ts'].toString();
        ...
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [listening for a list of values](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events).

Comment: im sorry i dont understand, can you help me

Comment: Did you try the code that I gave in my answer? What happened when you did?

Comment: erorr to builder

Comment: @ErickMahardika I'm really trying to help here, and it's definitely possible there's a mistake in the code I posted - but you'll need to do better in saying what you did with the code I gave an the error you got. If you tried to get it to work and get an error, edit your question (there's a link right under it) and show the updated code, and the error you got. That's also a good moment to read up on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).